# FactoryGirl not respecting callback order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, factory-bot, rails-activerecord

**Broken Case**

I have the following class

```
 class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :manufacturer
     belongs_to :production_plant
     before_save :delegate_audit_number

     attr_accessible :manufacturer_id, :production_plant_id, :audit_number
     private

        def delegate_audit_number
          self.audit_number ||= self.manufacturer.audits.last.try(:number)
        end
 end
```

and the following factory

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :vehicle do
      association :production_plant, factory: :production_plant
      after(:validation) do |v|
        v.manufacturer_id = v.production_plant.manufacturer_id
      end
    end
  end
```

Then calling `FactoryGirl.create(:vehicle)` fails in the `before_save` with

```
          Failure/Error: @vehicle = FactoryGirl.create(:vehicle)
             NoMethodError:
               undefined method `audits' for nil:NilClass
```

By debugging, I have discovered two things:

1) the manufacturer method is `nil` in the `before_save` callback

2) The `after_validation` callback is never hit.

**Working Case**

Identical in every way to the broken case, except the before_save is moved out into an observer

```
class AuditNumberObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :vehicle

  def before_save(entity)
    entity.audit_number ||= entity.manufacturer.audits.last.try(:number)
  end
end
```

Now it is my understanding (based on the following list in the documentation:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks
)

That `after_validation` should happen before `before_save`

Why is factory girl not respecting the callback chain in the first case?
Why is factory girl respecting the callback chain in the second case?
What is the difference?

Comment: flipping after validation to either build or create or stub did not fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the use of `after(:validation)` in the factory.

According to [FactoryGirl's README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks), this callback is not defined by the gem.

Comment: while a useful and educational suggestion, flipping the callback to  either build or create or stub as defined in the doc did not fix the problem